# Single monitor, windows start off screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

More often than not, new windows start on the second display area for which I have no monitor connected.
Is there any configuration to make sure new windows start on the primary display?
(Right now I do alt+space, then m, then left arrow until I see the window but it is impractical)

The raspberry has 2 HDMI outputs, one is connected to a fiscal display, the other one is not. If I drag a window around over the right edge of the screen, it disappears. I guess that the second screen is there, on the logical space on the right of my first monitor. The problem is that often new windows appear there and I cannot see them.

I basically need a way to control in which display windows open by default

Comment: What do you mean with *second display area*? What area? How do you connect a monitor to that area?

Comment: Please don't explain it in a comment. Add it to the question. Use the [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/120991/edit) link.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply run [`arandr`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/arandr.md) (Preferences -> Screen Configuration) and desactivate the HDMI output for which you have no display. You can re-activate it at any time if you want to use a second display.

Comment: there's no apparent option to disable that. I'll try to send you a picture.